# Xcode 11.4 Cast from 'Bool.Type' to unrelated type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') always fails

Tags: xcode11.4

Since Xcode 11.4, the following code:

```
override public class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass { // What do I transform
    return Bool.self as! AnyClass
}
```

gives a warning: `Cast from 'Bool.Type' to unrelated type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') always fails`

Tried replacing the `as!` with `as`, this removes the warning, but the app won't build anymore and the Buildtime displays: `error: Segmentation fault: 11`

What's going on with Xcode 11.4 and this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve this?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately